# Need help stringing together database processes

Tags: database, rss, extract, socrata

I need some help from those with more knowledge than I posses.  I am currently trying to figure out how to get real time data from a database.

I need to be able to find the company info from the most recent licensees.  So the search parameter I'm using is 2016-05-10T00:00:00.000

The full string together from the API and the search parameter can be found directly at this link:
https://www.hurl.it/?method=GET&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdata.wa.gov%2Fresource%2Fv8vv-gqqs.json&headers=%7B%22X-App-Token%22%3A[%22bjp8KrRvAPtuf809u1UXnI0Z8%22]%7D&args=%7B%22licenseeffectivedate%22%3A[%222004-07-14T00%3A00%3A00.000%22]%7D

So I'm looking to retrieve the most recently added accounts in order to verify 1. the license is active 2. the license number the contractor gives matches what the website says.  I would like to figure out how to automate this so that when the newest licenses are added I'll know, and they will be extracted/downloaded into excel.

If anyone can help with this I would appreciate it very much.  I also have more questions about using databases if any of you are experts in the field.

Once again, thank you!

Clay

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is to get this data into Excell, have you considered using something like [our OData support](https://dev.socrata.com/odata/) instead? You could structure your query in Excel PowerBI and it'd automatically refresh the data.

Another option would be to use our CSV output type with an [Excel web query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-external-data-from-a-Web-page-708f2249-9569-4ff9-a8a4-7ee5f1b1cfba). I use the `IMPORTDATA(...)` function in Google Sheets, which is very similar.